# when i write a tuple in a file i lost some values when i print it in console i get them all

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have this tuple

```
tuple=[(1,0.1),(2,0.2)...(714,7,14)] etc
```

When I use print (tuple) i get in the console what i expect

```
[(1,0.1),(2,0.2)...(100,1)]
```

When i try this:

```
for counter in range (0,100): 

 file.write('{}'.format(tuple))
```

I get what i expect as well in an .txt file i have already open.

But when i try to print my tuple line by line using:

```
for j in tuple:

 file.write(' '.join(str(s) for s in j) + '\n')
```

It does not write all the tuple instead it lost some values at the end of it.
Same thing happens on this approach:

```
for counter in range (0,100):

 file.write('{}'.format(Result[counter]))
```

I use python 3.7 from anaconda 
I write my code in spyder

Comment: I think you need to `pickle` the data before writing and `unpickle` after you read it.

Comment: Doesn't your first code print the full  tuple 100 times?

Comment: That's a list of tuples, not a tuple.

Comment: In your first `for` loop, did you mean to say `file.write('{}'.format(tuple[counter]))`?

Comment: Why are you using `range(0, 100)` when the list appears to have 714 elements?

Comment: Are you closing the file after you finish the loop? You need to do that to flush the last buffer.

Comment: @Barmar I didnt use 100 i use 714 just a mistake

Comment: Why don't you use `range(len(tuple))`?

Comment: @Barmar close the file of course!!!!! Thats why you need another one to debug..... Thanks a lot

Comment: Get in the habit of using `with open(filename, "w") as file:` so you don't forget to close.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the file at the end of the loop, to ensure that the output buffer is flushed to the file.

Use a context manager to ensure this:

```
with open("filename", "w") as file:
    #any for loop that writes to the file
```